# Gradle github and facebook dependencies can't resolve

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, resolve

I am new to gradle and was wondering if I am doing something wrong or not when i try to load dependencies from the main Maven repo

this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

and the error i get is

```
Error:(15, 17) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0

Error:(14, 17) Failed to resolve: com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2
```

What is going on? Why am i seeing those errors? This text here is only so that stackoverflow stop complaining.

UPDATE:

This is gradle-wrapper.settings:

```
#Tue Nov 17 20:36:30 GMT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

[image: gradle settings]

Those are my dependencies in Android Studio. It even found it through the search ....

[image: ANdroid studio deps]

Comment: Post your app.gradle

Comment: I dont have such file ? Where should it be ?

Comment: I mean your application gradle

Comment: Still no idea what this is or where to find it ... in my project, as far as I know, there is only this gradle file - build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you've forget to add the repository to your project. According to your build.script, you've added repo just in your buildscript. Just add repositories into the build.script root, before declaring dependencies, as:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
       }
     dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' }
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
}
```

Or try:

Gradle settings -> Then uncheck Offline work

Comment: Same errors. Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0; Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2

Comment: Thanks for helping ... now i get this error Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. ( With the edited version ... )

Comment: Same error 00:41:23: Executing external task 'clean'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '----/FriendsWithCars/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'FriendsWithCars'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.038 secs
Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
00:41:23: External task execution finished 'clean'.

Comment: This is what i get if i put "apply plugin" under dependencies ....
Error:(7, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'FriendsWithCars' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Comment: Is there a way to just download the .jar files for the 'fab' project and import them directly ?